# Project all properties

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

When creating an anonymous type, how can we have it populated with all the properties of an object and also with the properties of a property.

I am willing to achieve the below, but without manually specifying all the fields.

```
public class TestRb
{

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }

    public object Project(Person p)
    {
        return new
        {
            p.Name,
            p.Age,
            p.Address.Street,
            p.Address.City,
        };
        /*
        Instead of specifying maually all the fields, I would like to have 
        return new
        {
            p.*,
            p.Address.*,
        };*/
    }
```

Comment: What is the use case for this? In other words, why do you need an anonymous type?

Comment: @RQDQ I want to "flatten" an object in order to display it in a grid as single row.

Comment: You probably want https://automapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: It sounds more like you are trying to do a [deep copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

Comment: @IainGalloway, really nice project and indeed may solve my request but company policy are strict on external packages and I was hoping that something simple can solve this :)

Comment: @Toto - unfortunately, this is non trivial to solve well. To do this, you would have to walk the properties (ensuring that you don't end up in an infinite circular loop). Then you would have to deal with naming collisions, array / ienumerable types (will you try to flatten those someone with an index in the name).

Comment: @Toto: You won't be able to do this without reflection.  Out of curiosity, why is specifying the fields manually out of the question?  Where I work, using Reflection that heavily would never fly.

Comment: @user2588666 : manually adding the fields would work but having a generic way to flatten an object would 1/ save a lot of time (when having 50/100 fields...) 2/ prevent fields missing 3/ have any field later on added to be automatically populated on the flattened view

Answer (score 2):

Well, as already mentioned, this may be possible but is definitely not trivial.

The code below provides one possible (minimal) solution using dynamically generated types. Alternative solutions are possible using for example an `ExpandoObject`. The advantage of dynamically generated types is that they nicely include properties that can be discovered using regular reflection mechanisms and that it is possible to add specific utility methods or specific overloads (e.g. GetHashCode, Equals, ToString), although this is by no means trivial using IL.

The example below will fail, if there are nested properties that map to the same  property name. And likely there are other caveats. You may want to think hard about whether this is worth it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace TryOuts
{
    static class SO_28768330
    {
        public static class Mapper
        {
            private static readonly List<Type> _typesAsPrimitive;
            private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MapEntry> _map;
            private static Lazy<AssemblyName> MyDynamicAssemblyName;
            private static Lazy<AssemblyBuilder> MyDynamicAssemblyBuilder;
            private static Lazy<ModuleBuilder> MyDynamicModuleBuilder;

            static Mapper() 
            {
                _typesAsPrimitive = new List<Type>() { 
                    typeof(string), typeof(DateTime), typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(DateTimeOffset) 
                };
                _map = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MapEntry>();
                MyDynamicAssemblyName = new Lazy<AssemblyName>(
                    () => new AssemblyName("__My_Dynamic_Assembly__"), 
                    true);
                MyDynamicAssemblyBuilder = new Lazy<AssemblyBuilder>(
                    () => AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(MyDynamicAssemblyName.Value, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run), 
                    true);
                MyDynamicModuleBuilder = new Lazy<ModuleBuilder>(
                    () => MyDynamicAssemblyBuilder.Value.DefineDynamicModule("__My_Dynamic_Module__"),
                    true);
            }

            public static object FlattenToAnon<T>(T instance) where T : class
            {
                var entry = _map.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), (t) => BuildMapEntry<T>());
                return (instance != null) ? entry.Factory(instance) : instance;
            }

            private class MapEntry
            {
                public Type DynamicType;
                public Func<object, object> Factory;
            }

            private static MapEntry BuildMapEntry<T>()
            {
                var mapEntry = new MapEntry();
                var mappedType = typeof(T);
                var dynamicTypeName = "__Dynamic__" + mappedType.Name;
                var typeBuilder = MyDynamicModuleBuilder.Value.DefineType(dynamicTypeName, TypeAttributes.Public);
                var getterList = new List<Func<object, object>>();
                var setterList = new List<Action<object, object>>();
                var propertiesToMap = GetSourcePropertiesFor<T>(getterList);
                var mappedProperties = new List<PropertyBuilder>(propertiesToMap.Count);
                foreach (var p in propertiesToMap)
                {
                    var pb = AddProperty(typeBuilder, p.Name, p.PropertyType);
                    mappedProperties.Add(pb);
                }
                //OverrideToString(typeBuilder, mappedProperties);
                mapEntry.DynamicType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
                foreach (var p in mapEntry.DynamicType.GetProperties())
                    setterList.Add(BuildSetter(p));

                mapEntry.Factory = input =>
                {
                    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(mapEntry.DynamicType);
                    for (var i = 0; i < getterList.Count; i++)
                        setterList[i](instance, getterList[i](input));
                    return instance;
                };
                return mapEntry;
            }

            private static List<PropertyInfo> GetSourcePropertiesFor<T>(List<Func<object, object>> getters)
            {
                var props = new List<PropertyInfo>();
                var ps = typeof(T).GetProperties();
                foreach (var p in ps)
                {
                    var getter = BuildGetter(p);
                    if (!GetNestedSourceProperties(props, getters, p, getter))
                    {
                        props.Add(p);
                        getters.Add(getter);
                    }
                }
                return props;
            }

            private static bool GetNestedSourceProperties(List<PropertyInfo> props, List<Func<object, object>> getters, PropertyInfo nested, Func<object, object> parent_getter)
            {
                if (nested.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || _typesAsPrimitive.Contains(nested.PropertyType))
                    return false;

                var ps = nested.PropertyType.GetProperties();
                if (ps.Length == 0)
                    return false;

                foreach (var p in ps)
                {
                    var prop_getter = BuildGetter(p);
                    var getter = new Func<object, object>(obj => prop_getter(parent_getter(obj)));
                    if (!GetNestedSourceProperties(props, getters, p, getter))
                    {
                        props.Add(p);
                        getters.Add(getter);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            private static Func<object, object> BuildGetter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
            {
                var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instance");
                var instanceCast = propertyInfo.DeclaringType.IsValueType
                    ? Expression.Convert(instance, propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
                    : Expression.TypeAs(instance, propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
                var propertyCast = Expression.TypeAs(Expression.Property(instanceCast, propertyInfo), typeof(object));
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(propertyCast, instance).Compile();
            }

            private static Action<object, object> BuildSetter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
            {
                var setMethodInfo = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true);
                var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instance");
                var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");
                var instanceCast = propertyInfo.DeclaringType.IsValueType
                    ? Expression.Convert(instance, propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
                    : Expression.TypeAs(instance, propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
                var call = Expression.Call(instanceCast, setMethodInfo, Expression.Convert(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
                return Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(call, instance, value).Compile();
            }

            private static PropertyBuilder AddProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
            {
                const MethodAttributes getSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;

                var field = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);
                var property = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(
                    propertyName, PropertyAttributes.None, propertyType, new[] { propertyType });

                var getMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, getSetAttr, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
                var getIl = getMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
                getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
                getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                property.SetGetMethod(getMethodBuilder);

                var setMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName, getSetAttr, null, new[] { propertyType });
                var setIl = setMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
                setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
                setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                property.SetSetMethod(setMethodBuilder);

                return property;
            }
        }

        public class Address 
        {
            public string Street { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
        }
        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public Address Address { get; set; }
        }

        public static void TryIt()
        {
            var aPerson = new Person() { Age = 30, Name = "Joe Plummer", Address = new Address() { City = "Gotham", Street = "First Bat Street" } };
            var flattenedPerson = Mapper.FlattenToAnon(aPerson);
            var dynamicPerson = (dynamic)flattenedPerson;
            Console.WriteLine("Name   = {0}", dynamicPerson.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Age    = {0}", dynamicPerson.Age);
            Console.WriteLine("City   = {0}", dynamicPerson.City);
            Console.WriteLine("Street = {0}", dynamicPerson.Street);
        }
    }
}
```